# Error Message Undefined reference:

Tags: c

I have the following error messages, please help me why they are not working:

/tmp/ccKUDnGv.o: In function 'main':

Fork.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to 'Open'

Fork.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to 'Wait'

Fork.c:.text+0x36): undefined reference to 'Read'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

```
#include "csapp.h"

int main()
{
  int fd;
  char c;

  fd = Open("foobar.txt",O_RDONLY,0);
  if (Fork == 0)
  {
    Read(fd, &c, 1);
    exit(0);
  }
    Wait(NULL);
    Read(fd, &c, 1);
    printf("c = %c\n", c);
    exit(0);
}//end main()
```

Open, Wait and Read are included in "csapp.h" Here they are(The file is too large to post here so I am only putting what they look like):

```
  pid_t Wait(int *status);
  int Open(char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
  ssize_t Read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

Do I also need to include a csapp.c from somewhere?

Comment: `csapp.h` contains the declarations of the functions. Where are they defined? Did you include that file in your project?

Comment: Are the headers that define the functions from the error messages included in your `.cpp`? Indirectly by the `csapp.h` header?

Comment: Functions usually start with lower-case letters, so a guess would be that you should be calling `open`, `read` and `wait` instead, but without seeing the function definitions from the header, we can't help.

Comment: did you include `csapp.c` in your compile string? Or, if provided as a library, did you include the lib? E.g. `gcc -o progname progname.c csapp.c` or  `gcc -o progname progname.c -lcsapp`?

Comment: I tried the method provided in the answer below \/ and got the error msg shown, any ideas?

Comment: Sure its not lowercase `open()`, etc?

Comment: The way is is shown in both header and c files they are capitalized. I tried lower case for both in the header and c files and got same msg

Answer (score 0):

i find this `http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/ics2/code/src/csapp.c` on the Internet,maybe you need this c file. 
compile your code like this: `gcc yourfile.c csapp.c  -o  yourfile.out`

Comment: I got this error: csapp.c:184: error: conflicting types for âOpenâ
csapp.h:87: error: previous declaration of âOpenâ was here____Here's what it looks like in csapp.h: int Open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

Answer (score 0):

You also need the csapp.c file.

`http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/ics2/code/src/csapp.c`
`http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/ics3/code/src/csapp.c`